# Highlighting multiple dates in MonthCalender Control in window application

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar

I am creating an Event Calender using MonthCalender control in window application asp.net.

Can any one tell me how to highlight multiple dates in MonthCalender?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the BoldedDates property of the control to allow for 'multiple highlighted dates'.

This control does not inherently support highlighting multiple dates, so this is kind of a hack.

Comment: BoldedDates property only bolds the Dates in MonthCalender Control and i need to highlight

Comment: then you will have to write that feature yourself, or use WPF, in which it is already built in.